# I'm trying to get web scraped data to print in excel side by side instead of vertically

Tags: python, excel

I have scraped 2 data sets from a webpage and imported it to an xls file. \n allows me to re-run my program and print the data under the old data, but I would like to print the new data in the column next to the old data.

It pastes like this:

Old data
(new row)
New data

I would like it to paste like this:

Old data (new column) New data

I have tried using both \t and \n in my codes current format. I'm not sure if I have the arrangement wrong or if there's a different \command.

```
def main():
    import csv
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver

    ticker = input("Enter your ticker: ")
    url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=" + ticker.upper()
    print(url)

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)

    values_elementticker = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='gry']")
    values2 = values = [x.text for x in values_elementticker]
    print(values2[0])

    values_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='data_i97']")
    values = [x.text for x in values_element]
    print("Cash Flows:")
    print(values[0])



    with open("results.xls", "a") as f:
        for i in range(len(values2)):
            f.write(values2[0] + "\n")
        for i in range(len(values)):
            f.write(values[0] + "\n")

    browser.close()
    restart = input("Do you wish to start again?").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        main()

    else:
        exit()
main()
```

It currently prints like this

```
IBM

13,345

12,685

12,857

12,808

12,951

12,741

 ABB

2,547

2,819

2,942

3,012

2,850

1,923
```

I would like it to print like this in excel

```
  IBM     |   ABB

13,345   |   2,547

12,685   |   2,819

12,857   |   2,942

12,808   |  3,012

12,951   |   2,850

12,741   |   1,923
```

Comment: Does  `with open("results.xls", "a") as f:` make column A the active one? Perhaps you just need to do ` with open("results.xls", "b") as f:` for the second column?

Comment: I'm new to coding, this is actually my first program. With that being said, I believe that "a" allows me to append my scraped data to the excel sheet. I don't believe "a" has anything to do with the actually A column itself. I tired replacing "a" with "b" which is what I think you were suggesting and that broke the program. In CMD it gave me "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: oh yeah sorry, that's a switch for `open()`...I'll take a look

Comment: Can you use a module like [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html)? It can help you write your data in excel as per your specifications and much more.

Comment: I can, I just downloaded and I'll give it a go tonight. I'll let ya know if it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: xlsxwriter will definitely work for my needs if I spend some more time learning it. In fact, it's exactly what I need, so thank you sooooo much <3 :0. I'd mark your comment as the solution and give you an updoot but I don't know how to mark comments as solutions. If you want you can type it out in the answer section and I can do the rest from there. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this works in your given context, but reading and writing to a .csv file is much easier and faster. .xls files are designed to be opened with Excel (or similar) and contain formats, sheets and other multi-dimensional data that makes them rather complex to work with.

Since a .csv defines columns with commas, they are often easy and quick to read and write. And at the end of the day, you can still open a .csv with spreadsheet software so it can still be a functional solution.

My suggestion:

```
with open("results.csv", "a") as f:
    for x,y in zip(values2,values1):
        line = "%s,%s\n" % (x,y)
        f.write(line)
```

If you really insist on writing to an xls file, then it's probably best to go with a module specifically for that purpose, as suggested in Kamal's comment.

Comment: I messed around with your method of writing to a csv file instead and it kind of worked, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get exactly the results I was looking for. I will definitely consider this method in the future though, I've thought of a few ways it could very useful to me, so thank you for your comment.